# Clipping raster using vector layer in GeoServer

Tags: raster, geoserver, wms, clip, wps

I am trying to clip a raster layer using boundaries from a vector layer. I have tried using WPS chaining to do it. I have used gs:cropcoverage as input process for the raster and gs:collectgeometries as input process for vector. But the tags in output xml file from the vector are empty. When I am executing the process I am getting the error as

```
Failed to parse process inputs
```

[image]

This is my output XML.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier/>
  <wps:DataInputs/>
  <wps:ResponseForm/>
</wps:Execute>
```

Comment: check that the subprocesses return something to work out what's going wrong or look in the log file